# SQL Report Error - [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

We use a housing software based on ColdFusion and uses SQL to create database functions in our reports. I am working on a custom report to try to subtract one column from another: more specifically subtract `COUNT_OF_INSPECTION_TYPE` from `OCCUPANCY`. The `OCCUPANCY` column is based on the following code:

```
CONVERT(INT
        , CASE 
               WHEN tblHalls.HALLNAME = 'Hall1' THEN 198 
               WHEN tblHalls.HALLNAME = 'Hall2' THEN 430  
               WHEN tblHalls.HALLNAME = 'Hall3' THEN 333 
         END
      )
```

When I try a new function `OCCUPANCY - COUNT_OF_INSPECTION_TYPE`, I get an error:

> **Unable to invoke CFC - Error Executing Database Query.**  [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name
>   'OCCUPANCY'.

I'm not sure if I am explaining this right. I'd appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: What kind of function exactly? Which application is throwing the error? Without knowing more, this sounds like a SQL or reporting issue. However, it is hard to advise without more details.

Comment: This is the error I receive ERROR MESSAGE:
Unable to invoke CFC - Error Executing Database Query.

ERROR DETAIL:
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'OCCUPANCY'.

Comment: (Edit) Ohh... you cannot use an *alias* in a calculation at the same level (ie before it is defined). The choices are to either a) repeat the whole case statement in the calculation OR b) use another option like a CTE, derived query, the `apply operator etcetera. See http://sqlmag.com/blog/tip-apply-and-reuse-column-aliases

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you're talking about? I am struggling to understand. My knowledge of SQL is VERY BASIC.

Comment: SQL processes things out of the order that you code it in. Basic flow is: FROM >> WHERE >> GROUP BY >> HAVING >> SELECT >> ORDER BY >> TOP. You can't access a variable in a higher process.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot create an [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)) and use it in another calculation, at the same level, because the alias is not defined yet. Either repeat the whole `CASE ... END` statement in the calculation (less desirable) OR use another option, such as a [CTE, derived table, APPLY operator, etcetera](http://sqlmag.com/blog/tip-apply-and-reuse-column-aliases).

Wrapping your existing SELECT in a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) is probably one of the simplest options:

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
    -- Your current SELECT statement goes here
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(INT
                , CASE 
                       WHEN tblHalls.HALLNAME = 'Hall1' THEN 198 
                       WHEN tblHalls.HALLNAME = 'Hall2' THEN 430  
                       WHEN tblHalls.HALLNAME = 'Hall3' THEN 333 
                 END
        ) 
        AS OCCUPANCY
        , tblHalls.COUNT_OF_INSPECTION_TYPE
        , ... (Other Columns)
    FROM  tblHalls
)
-- Now use the alias in a calculation
SELECT cte.*
        , cte.OCCUPANCY - cte.COUNT_OF_INSPECTION_TYPE AS SomeAliasForThisCol
FROM   cte
```

Side note, since the CASE statement does not define an ELSE condition, the result of the calculation will be `NULL` if none of HallName's match. If that is not desirable, consider setting a default.